# Image picked from gallery always return -1 in OS 5.x (lollipop) android

Tags: android, imageview, cursor, gallery

I am opening the phones Gallery app and selecting the image , to show display it in `Imageview`, for that I am compressing the gallery image .

While I select the image from the `Gallery` it throws Error

Activity.java

```
private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 102);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 102) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                bitmap = imageCompressor.compressImage(imageUri.toString());

                //String imagePath=methods.getPath(imageUri);

                imageviewCapture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageviewCapture.setOnClickListener(null);

                cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageviewGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageviewGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    }
```

ImageCompressor.java

```
public Bitmap compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
```

Error :

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=102, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:19003 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.techmorphosis.tottle/com.techmorphosis.tottle.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.



java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: Why do you want a real path from uri?

Comment: for this :  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

Comment: Better use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() if that exists.

Comment: not possible :( , but what's problem with current code ?

Comment: ??? You told what the problem was. And why isn't it possible?

Comment: @karthik :  Activity.RESULT_OK = -1 so you get the success result on your onActivityResult.

Comment: ???? What are you trying to tell???

Comment: My original code is working fine with samsung GT-18190N , os : 4.1.2 , but not with os :5.x

Comment: You better tell why it was not possible.